# In Azure Release Pipeline while using $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) as variable value, it is throwing System.FormatException Exception

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

While running Integration Test in my project using Azure Release Pipeline, I am using $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to substitute one of my variable in appsetting.release.json through release pipeline in variables tab.

but throwing below error on running :

System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'a' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 13 | BytePositionInLine: 27.

Could someone help me in resolving this error. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show part of json file where you want to replace variable?

Comment: @kr below is the section:
"DATAppSettings": {
    "FileShareLocation": ""DATAppSettings": {
    "FileShareLocation": "#{DAT.FilePath}"
  },"
  },

I am replacing #{DAT.FilePath} with $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Comment: Can you show what is inside `DAT.FilePath`?

Comment: DAT.FilePath = 
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Answer (score 1):

You're using Windows-style filepaths, i.e. `C:\foo\bar`. `\` represents an escape character in JSON. So if the file path is `C:\a\src\`, it's interpreting `\a` as an escape character and failing.

You need to escape the `\` by making it `\\`.